# easyhookでexttextoutwをフックしたい

Tags: c#, windows

[EasyHook-Tutorialsのサンプル](https://github.com/EasyHook/EasyHook-Tutorials/tree/master/Managed/RemoteFileMonitor)を変更して、exttextoutwをフックするようにプログラムを書きました。しかし、notepad.exeで実行してもhookのメッセージが表示されません。

なにが悪いのでしょうか？

変更したコードは下記のとおりです。
FileMonitorHook以外は変更しておりません。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileMonitorHook
{
    public class InjectionEntryPoint: EasyHook.IEntryPoint
    {
        ServerInterface _server = null;
        Queue<string> _messageQueue = new Queue<string>();

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public long left;
            public long top;
            public long right;
            public long bottom;
        }

        public InjectionEntryPoint(
            EasyHook.RemoteHooking.IContext context,
            string channelName)
        {
            _server = EasyHook.RemoteHooking.IpcConnectClient<ServerInterface>(channelName);
            _server.Ping();
        }

        public void Run(
            EasyHook.RemoteHooking.IContext context,
            string channelName)
        {
            _server.IsInstalled(EasyHook.RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId());

            var ExtTextOutHook = EasyHook.LocalHook.Create(
                EasyHook.LocalHook.GetProcAddress("Gdi32.dll", "ExtTextOutW"),
                new ExtTextOut_Delegate(ExtTextOut_Hook),
                this);

            _server.ReportMessage("ExtTextOut hook installed");

            EasyHook.RemoteHooking.WakeUpProcess();

            try
            {
                // Loop until FileMonitor closes (i.e. IPC fails)
                while (true)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    string[] queued = null;
                    lock (_messageQueue)
                    {
                        queued = _messageQueue.ToArray();
                        _messageQueue.Clear();
                    }
                    if (queued != null && queued.Length > 0)
                    {
                        _server.ReportMessages(queued);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _server.Ping();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            ExtTextOutHook.Dispose();
            EasyHook.LocalHook.Release();
        }

        #region ExtTextOutW Hook

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall,
                    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
                    SetLastError = true)]
        delegate bool ExtTextOut_Delegate(
            IntPtr hdc,
            int x,
            int y,
            uint fuOptions,
            [In] ref RECT lprc,
            string lpString,
            uint cbCount,
            [In] IntPtr lpDx);

        [DllImport("Gdi32.dll",
            CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
            SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern bool ExtTextOutW(
            IntPtr hdc,
            int x,
            int y,
            uint fuOptions,
            [In] ref RECT lprc,
            string lpString,
            uint cbCount,
            [In] IntPtr lpDx);

        bool ExtTextOut_Hook(
            IntPtr hdc,
            int x,
            int y,
            uint fuOptions,
            [In] ref RECT lprc,
            string lpString,
            uint cbCount,
            [In] IntPtr lpDx)
        {
            try
            {
                lock (this._messageQueue)
                {
                    this._messageQueue.Enqueue("ExtTextOut_Hook called");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return ExtTextOutW(
                hdc,
                x,
                y,
                fuOptions,
                ref lprc,
                lpString,
                cbCount,
                lpDx);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

手元のWindows 10ではnotepad.exeは`ExtTextOutW`を使っておらず`TextOutW`を使っているようです。

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>dumpbin /imports:gdi32.dll c:\windows\notepad.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file c:\windows\notepad.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Section contains the following imports:

    GDI32.dll
             14001A708 Import Address Table
             14001F640 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                         2C1 GetTextFaceW
                          3D CreateDCW
                         5E3 StartPage
                         5E0 StartDocW
                         59E SetAbortProc
                         156 DeleteDC
                         168 EndDoc
                           0 AbortDoc
                         16C EndPage
                         2C4 GetTextMetricsW
                         5A5 SetBkMode
                         2D7 LPtoDP
                         5DB SetWindowExtEx
                         5D7 SetViewportExtEx
                         5BC SetMapMode
                         2BA GetTextExtentPoint32W
                         5EE TextOutW
                         1A5 EnumFontsW
                         59B SelectObject
                         15A DeleteObject
                          4D CreateFontIndirectW
                         25D GetDeviceCaps

  Summary

        3000 .data
        1000 .pdata
        8000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
       1A000 .rsrc
       19000 .text
```

Comment: ExtTextOutHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
が抜けていたのが問題でした。これでキャプチャできました。

ただ、notepadでabcと入力するとDEFと文字列が渡ってきてしまいます。これはまだなぜかはわかりません。